# edit and delete tr dynamically in table with javascript

Tags: javascript, dom, html-table

I am preparing a table and creating rows dynamically with javascript. This Table would have input given by user. It would have three main features.
  The first feature of the table is : As the user would add details and click on 'Add' button. a new row would add to table containing  the input given by user.
The second one is: As  the user would click on any row of the table the respected data of the rows would be shown in the input form.
The last feature is: As user clicks on the rows he could delete and edit that selected row.

I could add rows in table but the later part I am not getting that how to do..

 jss fiddle :http://jsfiddle.net/avnesh/N7tza/2/

```
<table border="1" id="table">
<tr id="myRow">
    <td>First cell</td>
    <td>Second cell</td>
    <td>Third cell</td>
</tr>
</table>
<br>
<input type="text" id='inputone' />
<input type="text" id='inputtwo' />
<input type="text" id='inputthree' />
<button onclick="myFunction()">Add to table</button>
<button onclick="deleteTr();">delete</button>
<script>
myFunction = function () {
input1 = document.getElementById('inputone');
Value1 = input1.value;
input2 = document.getElementById('inputtwo');
Value2 = input2.value;
input3 = document.getElementById('inputthree');
Value3 = input3.value;
R = document.getElementById("table").rows.length;
one = 1;
I = R + one;
var table = document.getElementById("table");
var x = table.insertRow(0);
x.insertCell(0).innerHTML = "<input type='text' value='" + Value3 + "' name='" + I + "'>";
x.insertCell(0).innerHTML = "<input type='text' value='" + Value2 + "' name='" + I + "'>";
x.insertCell(0).innerHTML = "<input type='text' value='" + Value1 + "' name='" + I + "'>";
} //end myFunction

assignTrIndex = function () {
var rows = document.getElementById('table').rows;
for (var i = 0; i <= rows.length; i++) {
    rows[i].onclick = getRowIndex(this)
}
}

var rowIndx = '';
getRowIndex = function (z) {
//alert(z.rowIndex);    
var rowIndx = z.rowIndex;
}

deleteTr = function () {
document.getElementById('table').deleteRow(rowIndx);
}
</script>
```

`

p.s.

I am trying to call row index in delete function(deleteTr) to delete that selected row. So I am assigning a function of getting row index(assignTrIndex) on table rows but it is not working.I am using Jquery only to produce Input form for user. I want to solve this problem with javascript only.

thanks in advance ..

Comment: Hi, Do you have any code samples of what you have tried. My first thought would be JQuery might help you here.

Comment: So do you want jQuery or not?

Comment: jss fiddle is there http://jsfiddle.net/avnesh/N7tza/2/

Comment: i don't want j-query soulution

Comment: @melomane but you're already use jquery UI?

Comment: I used it to produce input form.(I used it to save time on jss fiddle later i would use javascript in my actual programme ). but the table works dynamically by javascript.

Comment: This will get your row index on tr click `x.onclick = function(e){
        alert(this.rowIndex);  
}`

Comment: @Nouphal.M as I am creating tr dynamically how assign the function on click tr

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First change this line from

```
var x = table.insertRow(0);
```

to

```
var x = table.insertRow(R);
```

so that rows get added at the end of the table.

The you need to add a click event listener to your table row while you create them and populate the values back in text box

```
x.onclick = function (e) {
        rInd = this.rowIndex; // get row index for delete
        var value = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) { // iterate through cells you can also get cell count for now i am making it static
            var cell0 = x.cells[i];
            var inp1 = cell0.getElementsByTagName('input'); // find input in cells
            value.push(inp1[0].value); // save the value
        }
        document.getElementById('inputone').value = value[0];
        document.getElementById('inputtwo').value = value[1];
        document.getElementById('inputthree').value = value[2];
    }
```

Delete code

```
deleteTr = function (rowIndx) {
    document.getElementById('table').deleteRow(rInd);
}
```

Working Demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Jjua9/3/)